# Script to copy and add date/time stamp and ensure they get copied to the correct folders

Tags: batch-file

Both servers have the exact same folder structure, however when I run the script to copy from ServerA to Server B, on ServerB instead of placing the file in the same folder, it puts in the root. There is a parent folder, in this parent folder there are 3 different folders. If the file is in ServerA>Folder1>Client, then when running the script it must but it in ServerB>Folder1>Client. and not in the root or any other folder.

This is the script;

```
@echo off
SetLocal

:: prepare date/time stamp
for /f "Tokens=1-4 Delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set dt=%%i-%%j-%%k-%%l
for /f "Tokens=1" %%i in ('time /t') do set tm=-%%i

:: timestamp (yyyymmmdd-hhnnss)
set tm=%tm::=-%
set dtt=%dt%%tm%

:: directories
Set "sourcefolder=E:\IC_Batch\iCompareTest\10x"
Set "destinationfolder=\\mmdkfvdev08\E$\IC_Batch\10x\"

:: copy files
For /f "delims=" %%a in (
 'Dir /a-D /b /s "%sourcefolder%\*.*" 2^>nul'
 ) do If exist "%%a" (
 xcopy /s /c /d /i /y "%%a" "%destinationfolder%\%dtt%-%%~na.*"

)

EndLocal
```

Comment: You don't appear to have grasped the use of the `XCOPY` and `DIR` commands. Enter, `XCOPY/?` and `DIR/?` for information then decide if you intend to copy 'individual files' or 'directories' from the source directory. Try copying in a pre-created test environment until you are sure of the correct `XCOPY` syntax then you can test the `DIR` command until you are sure that it's output matches the input you require for your validated `XCOPY` command. Then put it together in your script, trying all the time to ignore that fact that `XCOPY` was superseded by `ROBOCOPY` as far back as Windows Vista.

Comment: I do not know anything about scripting, hence why I am asking for help. The script above was taken from another forum.